# confusion in Meta characters of perl

Tags: perl, metacharacters

When I run the below program, it gave me nothing ("") as result.
Scenario 1:-

```
$var = "A STITCH IN TIME SAVES NINE";
       if ($var =~ /[1..9]/i) {
         print "FOUND\n"
      }
```

But when I add space before and after '..' operator,  it threw " Found and is " as a result.

Scenario :- 2

```
 $var = "A STITCH IN TIME SAVES NINE";
           if ($var =~ /[1 .. 9]/i) {
             print "FOUND\n"
          }
```

Could anyone explain me what is happening here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex language is *embedded* in Perl (and vice versa), but it shares no syntax with Perl¹. This means other sytax for repetition or ranges.

<sub>1) Regexes share syntax with Perl strings, although the two are not fully compatible, see different meanings of the `\b` escape.</sub>

Character classes define a set of multiple properties. The character class will match if one of the specified properties will match. A charclass can contain:

- single characters, like `[aeiou]` (match lowercase vowels)
- ranges, to match continuous ranges of code points: `[A-Z]` (uppercase latin characters)
- negation of the whole charclass: `[^']` (everything that is not a single quote)
- named charclasses like `\d`, `\w` (and a lot of fun with Unicode properties)
- (POSIX charclasses)

If a charclass contains a character multiple times, this is irrelevant, as it behaves like a set union.

The metacharacters in charclasses are

- `]`: end of match. To match square brackets, one has to do `[\[\]]` or `[][]`, as a charclass *cannot* be empty.
- The negation operator `^` which is only special in leading position: `[~&|^]` would match any of the bitwise logical Perl operators.
- The range operator `-`. To match a literal minus, it can be put at the end of the charclass: The class `[+-*]` would be invalid (`*` comes before `+`, so the class is empty, which is illegal), but `[+*-]` works just fine
- The backslash still is the escape character.

Space is significant inside charclasses, even under the `/x` flag.

#### On your charclasses:

- `[1..9]` could also be written as `[19.]`, and matches a `1`, `9` or `.`, as the period is *not* a metacharacter inside charclasses.
- `[1 .. 9]` could be written `[19. ]`, and additionally matches a space. As I said above, whitespace is significant in charclasses.

#### What you probably meant:

If you want to match any of the digits `0` or `1` to `9`, you can use the range `[0-9]`. Remember that the minus is the range operator in charclasses.

Comment: Thank you very much, This is really a very usefule information. Thanks again for sharing this with me.

Answer (score 5):

> When I run the below program, it gave me nothing ("") as result.

The string does not contain a 1, a full stop, or a 9. The pattern does not match anything in the string.

> But when I add space before and after '..' operator, it threw " Found and is " as a result

It does contain a multiple spaces.
When you expand your character class to match against to include spaces, it matches.

> I have also include "$i" in the statement, but still it did not showed any value.

You never define `$i`. You only try to read from it.

Answer (score 4):

The ".." does not indicate a range in your character class, it indicates a full stop (twice :-)). You don't have either a 1 , full-stop or 9 in your string, so it does not match first time round.

Also, you are not populating $i anywhere. $i is just a regular scalar variable, it does not get magically populated with anything. The i flag on the end of your regular-expression (/i) means case-insensitive search (in case you thought that was populating $i